# Cache not getting cleared of Android Application programmatically?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

In my app because I use Bitmap factory to get bitmap image object from http url lot of data is getting cached. So i wrote following code to clear cache data everytime application loads. Its similar to what we do manually by clicking Clear Cache button in Setting -> Apps -> YOUR_APP.

However following code i wrote is not working. Cache size is as it is.

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib") && !s.equals("shared_prefs")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
```

I also added following permission in AndroidManifest.xml of my application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
```

Please help. And how we use Bitmap factory in efficient way to reduce performance and improve efficiency.

Comment: android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES add even this permission...

Comment: This permission  is only granted to system apps

Comment: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically  try to refer this tutorial...

Comment: That is not working i tried same tut... Cache data now shows 1.25mb whereas when i run code it remains same.. :(